# Not able to upload large files in amazon s3

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to upload large files like audio and video in amazon s3, django is throwing worker timeout. If so i use different credentials then its working fine. Just replacing the credentials of other account does the work. When I revert back the credentials to the other account it’s failing. But it works for small files less than 3mb. I hope I might have missed out some settings in my amazon s3 dashboard for this particular account. could anyone help me out?

Comment: Both of the AWS accounts are in same region?

Comment: Nope, both are in different regions.
Working one is in Singapore and the other one is in Oregon. I will try switching the region. Will it makes any difference?

Comment: It can be the reason. As inter region communication is over internet. Whereas inside a region communication is like LAN in AWS. Although for AWS even communication over internet is also very fast but you might have set the timeout to low that transactions in the same region complete but inter region transactions fail because they take more time and your worker timeouts.

Comment: I tried with same region, still its not working.

Comment: You can test by increasing worker timeout? Or by debugging the code where you are uploading files to S3.

Comment: Is there any difference in permissions between the two sets of credentials? Are both able to complete Multi Part Uploads?